# Force start with specific root node using decision trees in R

Tags: r, classification, cart

I'm using decision trees in R, with

```
    library("party")
    ctree.dt <- ctree(Pasillo_Ataque_2T ~ Dist_Col_1T + Dist_1T_2T, data=dt)
```

This produces:

[image]

It's correct, but I'd like ctree to start with the root node Dist_Col_1T, not Dist_1T_2T like in the image.

In [SPSS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/spss/tree/idh_idd_treegui_main.htm), I can force start a tree with a specific node variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `party` package (or its recommended reimplementation in the `partykit` package) this is not directly possible. You would have to first estimate the root stump with only the desired variable and `maxdepth = 1`. And then you would have to make separate `ctree()` calls in the resulting subsamples.